# Have a GFCI that trips when the ground and neutral are connected to the breaker and no phase wire

Tags: gfci

I have a 2 pole 20A GFCI.

When the neutral and the ground are connected the breaker trips with no phase conductors connected.

Comment: OK stop. Connect the ground FIRST and ALWAYS before you connect anything else.  If it still fails, it's a problem with the neutral wire.  Don't go thinking there's a problem with grounding things... grounds are always good.

Answer (score 3):

That would indicate that the neutral you are connecting is **either** not the neutral for the circuit that you have not connected the hot conductor(s) for, **or** is connected (improperly) to another neutral elsewhere.

GFCI's trip on a difference between the neutral current and the hot current [or the two hot currents, +/- the neutral given it's a two-pole].

Thus, there is current flowing on this neutral, (and not on the hot conductors which you have not connected) which there should not be if it's wired correctly, so it's not wired correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar issue when connecting my dryer.  It was originally wired for a 3 prong, but my house has the 4 prong outlet.  So when I wired it up and plugged it in, it kept tripping the breaker even when the machine wasn't on.  After some diagnosis, I learned it would only trip once the ground and neutral terminals were both connected - even if the 2 hot wires werent connected (and verified neutral up to the washer was wired correctly and not hot).  I discovered that behind the terminal, the neutral and ground were wired together.  I didn't realize this could cause a GFCI breaker to trip even if no current is flowing, but that seemed to be the case.  So perhaps also check for an unintentional ground/neutral connection somewhere.